# Visual studio 2017 .net standard missing assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

[image]

I always used .NET Framework till recent versions, now using Visual Studio 2017 i meet for the first time .NET Standard: ok is new and it include .NET Framework and so on, but why if a create a new class library project i start with these errors? I don't find anything on the web that let me know if it's a visual studio bug or not.

I have to understand Visual Studio again? In all previous version when an assembly was missing i used reference to add it and now what i have to do? If someone could be so kind to help me...

Comment: Happens on my machine as well, IntelliSense is quite slow for a .NETCore project.  It does catch up, eventually.  The tooling has many blemishes, feels like beta quality.  You might also want to keep an eye on Task Manager, Processes tab.  My anti-malware (stock Defender) really hates VS2017 and I have not yet found a way to slap it over the head, other than disabling it.

Comment: IntelliSense is pretty slow, and waiting may help; however, if it doesn't resolve within (about) 1 minute, it's worth potentially adding in the library from nuget as suggested in my response below.

Answer (score 0):

References have been replaced with Dependencies. Dependencies should expand and include an SDK node that contains the framework assemblies.

Like this:
https://joshuachini.com/2017/03/12/some-things-i-learned-while-getting-started-with-net-standard/

From your screenshot the Dependencies are not expandable, so something is wrong with the project.

Could it be that your Visual Studio 2017 is not up to date? Support for .NET standard has been updated at least in 15.3, 15.5 and possibly again later.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click  on dependencies in the project

```
* Select "Manage nuget package"
* search for dll that you want to add reference 
(Example: System.Configuration)
* Install
```